# Set the value of a <select> as it is popualted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am populating a select list with a PHP MySQL query. At the same time, I also want to set the select value to the current value in the db. It goes as such

1) Query the associated table and populate the `<select>` with each entry as an `<option>`

2) Set the `<select>` value to the current entry in the database

Right now I am doing this, but when I view the page the `<select>` is simply at the first option value.

```
echo '
<select name = "arena" type = "text" value = "'.$row['arena'].'">   ';
                    try{
                            $retrieveArena = $db->prepare("SELECT arena_id AS key1, arena_name AS val1 FROM arenas");
                            $retrieveArena->execute();
                            $retrieveArenaResult = $retrieveArena->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            if ($retrieveArena->rowCount() > 0){
                                foreach ($retrieveArenaResult as $arena){
                                    echo '<option value = "'.$arena['key1'].'">'. $arena['val1'].'</option>
                                    ';
                                }
                            }else{
                                returnMsg("No arenas found");   
                            }
                        }
                        catch(PDOException $e){
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
    echo '
    </select>';
```

Comment: I advice you to change `$row['arena']` to `htmlspecialchars($row['arena'])`. And, where are you "setting the select value to the current entry in the database"?

Comment: It's coming from a query before. This arena query is a nested query just to populate a select list for a form. Also I am using PDO do I need to do htmlspecialchars?

Comment: For me it's a bit hard to predict things when I can't see all the code. If the problem lies in the select not selecting the right element for starters, then why haven't you sent the part where that happens? And if PDO validates things like ">" and quotes, then `htmlspecialchars()` may not be necessary (don't know too much about PDO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the correct `<option>` tag the `selected` attribute.  So you will need to know what the selected option should be.  Then you can use code like this to build the options.

```
foreach ($retrieveArenaResult as $arena){
  echo '<option value = "' . $arena['key1'] .'"';

  if (this option is selected) {
    echo ' selected';
  }

  echo '>'. $arena['val1'].'</option>
                                   ';
}
```